How to fix object overflowing issue on a page in flutter?
I am very much new(learning) to Flutter and Dart, trying to create a simple login page like below.
class PageController extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageController({super.key});  // Constructor

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PageControllerState();
  }

}


class _PageControllerState extends State<PageController> {
  var activeScreen = 'login_screen';
  void switchScreen() {
    setState(() {
      activeScreen = 'home_page';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget screenWidget = LoginScreen(switchScreen);
    return CupertinoApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          child: screenWidget),
    );
  }
}

Would like to maintain Widget(s) in another class to call them accordingly in my main class above:
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  const LoginScreen(this.login, {super.key});
  final void Function() login;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column (
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 80,),

          const TextField( // Email starts
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Email',
            ),
          ), // email ends

          const TextField( // password starts
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Password',
            ),
          ), // password ends

          CupertinoButton( // Login button starts
            onPressed: login,
            child: const Row (
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(CupertinoIcons.play_fill, color: Colors.white),
                SizedBox(width: 8),
                Text("Login", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
              ],
            )
          ) // Login button ends
        ],
    ),);
  }
}

When I render the app I get an error message:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 199192 pixels on the


I trief adding padding the text fields:
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0)

But it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I fix it?

hii !! first you have to create a material app in your flutter application like this
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

